# Angular nativescript custom modal position absolute not working

Tags: angular, sass, nativescript, angular-nativescript

I'm using **NativeScript** with **Angular**, I'm trying to use a custom modal to show modal to half of the page, the background needs to be transparent. I have use position absolute to the component which I have created as a modal. but it is not working. can anyone suggest an idea? thanks in advance. I have attached my code below:

**SCSS code:**

```
.cv-modal {
  animation-name: fadein;
  animation-duration: 0.2s;
  z-index: 9999;

  &-bottom {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);

    .modal-container {
      border-top-right-radius: 25;
      border-top-left-radius: 25;
      width: 100%;
      background-color: #fff;
      animation-name: slideInUp;
      animation-duration: 0.3s;
    }
  }

}

@keyframes slideInUp {
  from {
    transform: translate(0, 3000);
  }
  to {
    transform: translate(0, 0);
  }
}

@keyframes fadein {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<FlexboxLayout class="my-events-container" flexDirection="column" style="position: relative">
        <ns-modal *ngIf="showModal" [position]="'bottom'" (close)="showModal = false">
            <ns-event-attendance></ns-event-attendance>
        </ns-modal>
        <StackLayout>
            <ListView class="cv-list" [items]="data" (itemTap)="showModal = true">
                <ng-template let-item="item" let-i="index">
                    <FlexboxLayout class="cv-list-item" alignItems="center">
                        <StackLayout class="list-item-l today">
                            <Label class="list-item-number" text="5"></Label>
                            <Label class="list-item-text" text="Nov"></Label>
                        </StackLayout>
                        <StackLayout class="list-item-c">
                            <FlexboxLayout flexDirection="column">
                                <Label class="list-item-heading" [text]='item.name'></Label>
                                <Label class="list-item-sub" [text]='item.location'></Label>
                                <Label class="list-item-last" [text]='item.location'></Label>
                            </FlexboxLayout>
                        </StackLayout>
                        <FlexboxLayout class="list-item-r">
                            <Label class="list-item-dot"></Label>
                        </FlexboxLayout>
                    </FlexboxLayout>
                </ng-template>
            </ListView>
        </StackLayout>
    </FlexboxLayout>
```

**modal.component.html**

```
<AbsoluteLayout class="cv-modal cv-modal-bottom" style="position: absolute" >
    <ng-container *ngIf="position === 'bottom'">
        <FlexboxLayout alignItems="flex-end" width="100%" height="100%">
            <StackLayout (tap)="closeModal()" class="modal-container">
                <FlexboxLayout  justifyContent="center" padding="20">
                    <StackLayout  width="45" borderRadius="10" height="4" backgroundColor="#a9a9a9"></StackLayout>
                </FlexboxLayout>
                <FlexboxLayout flexDirection="column">
                    <Label class="text-heading" text="testing"></Label>
                    <Label class="list-item-sub" text="xxxx"></Label>
                    <Label class="list-item-last" text="yyyy"></Label>
                </FlexboxLayout>
            </StackLayout>
        </FlexboxLayout>
    </ng-container>
</AbsoluteLayout>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO create stackblitz or share your code

Comment: @Chellappan posted the code please check

Comment: are you trying to position the model?

Comment: @chellapan yes want to position the modal

Comment: `position` is not a valid CSS attribute, by default everything inside AbsoluteLayout are positioned by fixed points (top & left). Honestly it seems too much of code, would you mind posting all together in a Playground so it may be easy to debug?